# Why using Ubuntu get empty laptop's battery?

Tags: battery

I used to use windows but I've moved to Ubuntu recently.

When i work on Ubuntu, then suddenly the battery get empty.

when i used Windows everything worked as well, but it seems Ubuntu isn't compatible with

laptops.

Comment: "but it seems Ubuntu isn't compatible with laptops." do not generalize please. MY laptop works PERFECTLY with Ubuntu. I even get 1h MORE than with W7. For us to help we need specifics. Let's start with make, model of your laptop and what graph card is in it. Otherwise this is niot a question but a rant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue with Ubuntu, and it is usually due to the graphics card driver, at least in my experience. If you have an Nvidia graphics card, try to install the privative drivers or better try to install nouveau: http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/ .

Comment: I've checked the graphic card's driver by lspci command but it has been installed.it seems another reason is caused the problem to be occurred.

Comment: I'm sorry. Every hardware configuration can have different issues with the software. I tried to help by explaining a common issue, and one that occurred to me, and how did I solve it. I hope you can find what's wrong.